# Square brackets in #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was going through the Linux Kernel code and found below line.  What do the square brackets mean?

```
#define __BPF_FUNC_STR_FN(x) [BPF_FUNC_ ## x] = __stringify(bpf_ ## x)
```

From:  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/disasm.c#n18

It's used like this:

```
static const char * const func_id_str[] = {
    __BPF_FUNC_MAPPER(__BPF_FUNC_STR_FN)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c99, a syntax was introduced for designated initializers. The square bracket syntax is for array initialization. So the line:

```
int a[] = { [10] = 4 };
```

will create an array `a` that can hold 11 `int`s, and initializes `a[10]` to 4, and the rest of its members initialized to 0.